# Monitor refresh rate dropped

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi, refresh-rate

Today I bought HDMI cable to connet my tv as a "secondary monitor" to my pc. But after I've plugged it in, the refresh rate on the main monitor dropped significantly.

Any info I find in the AMD control center still shows the expected value, but to be fair, I can't even select between the two plugged devices in there.

When I remove the HDMI cable from pc, the refresh rate goes back to normal, but I would like to keep it in.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Bandwidth limit? Higher (total) resolutions may be supported at lower refresh rates. There's only so much data the (video) RAM can provide in a given time. Check the specs.

Comment: You don't indicate what operating system, I presume Windows, which means that depending on the version it might not support handling different refresh rates on multiple displays.  Windows 8 and higher got significant multiple display improvements.

Comment: Sorry, it's win 7 64 bit. I have this popup to upgrade to win 10 hanging here for couple of months, maybe now it's the time?